# PHP Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 87

Tags: php

Any idea what is the problem? Its generate 9GB+ error log file.

```
// restore noise to html content
        function restore_noise($text) {
            while (($pos=strpos($text, '___noise___'))!==false) {
                $key = '___noise___'.$text[$pos+11].$text[$pos+12].$text[$pos+13];
                if (isset($this->noise[$key]))
                    $text = substr($text, 0, $pos).$this->noise[$key].substr($text, $pos+14);
            }
            return $text;
        }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the index 87 does not exists on one of the targeted arrays.
You should also use isset() on the highest used $text[$pos] (+13) before calling it.

```
// restore noise to html content
    function restore_noise($text) {
        while (($pos=strpos($text, '___noise___'))!==false
               && isset($text[$pos+13])) /*check the position index exists, or stop. (maybe you want to check this below instead of in the while statement, unless any undefined index is a reason to stop altogether*/{
            $key = '___noise___'.$text[$pos+11].$text[$pos+12].$text[$pos+13];
            if (isset($this->noise[$key]))
                $text = substr($text, 0, $pos).$this->noise[$key].substr($text, $pos+14);
        }
        return $text;
    }
```